# How to read bytes from memory

Tags: memory, size, offset

I wanted to ask 2 questions..there is a game and someone created some kind of anti-cheat for it. He also put in a scripting feature, where you can read maximum 4 bytes of a player's memory-adress you choose (from the game's process)..

I paste an examplescript here on how to USE it:

```html
public OnPlayerStateChange(playerid, newstate, oldstate)
{
    if(newstate == PLAYER_STATE_DRIVER || newstate == PLAYER_STATE_PASSENGER)
    {
        // read 1 byte from 0x8CB7A5 representing the radio station player is currently listening to.
        CAC_ReadMemory(playerid, 0x8CB7A5, 1);
    }
    return 1;
}

public CAC_OnMemoryRead(player_id, address, size, const content[])
{
    if(address == 0x8CB7A5 && size == 1)
    {
        // "content" is an array with "size" elements, each cell containing 1 byte.
        // We read only 1 byte, so the station id is at index 0.
        if(content[0] == 0x07) // 0x07 = Radio X
        {
            SendClientMessage(player_id, -1, "Radio X is indeed the best station.");
        }
        else
        {
            SendClientMessage(player_id, -1, "What the hell are you listening to ?!");
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

So the problem is that I have no idea how I find out a specific address..my goal is to find out an adress of a SPECIFIC .dll (which people inject to "cheat") that I can BAN the person from the game with a script...so I have this specific file on my deskop and I have no idea how to even start to find out what kind of memory-address this file would use if injected..

Thanks for any help in advance :)